# How to Setting compileSdkVersion in build.gradle before create a new project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I want to set compileSdkVersion to 17, but just cannot find where to change the default setting.

When I create new project, the compileSdkVersion is always 22...

Comment: Android studio auto set the latest api version, that you already have installed. So, i think you just can change it manual after create project.

Comment: I think studio by default sets the latest SDK version as the compile one.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have newer sdk so compileSdkVersion have to set that sdk version in default.

1.you can delete newer sdk ;-)

2.you can change that in build.gradle

my choice is 2.